# Combining pairs of depends numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have pairs of numpys such as the follows:

```
prv_path = np.array([[1,2,3],
                     [1,2,1],
                     [3,1,2],
                     [4,4,4]])
new_path = np.array([[3,1],
                     [3,2],
                     [3,4],
                     [4,3]])
```

`prv_path`  represents the old path and `new_path`  represents the new path.
I want to connect them to **new numpy** so that the path will appear in full.
The connection should be through the last column in `prv_path`  and the first column in `new_path` 
I.e. in the example above the path should be:

```
[[1,2,3,1],
 [1,2,3,2],
 [1,2,3,4],
 [4,4,4,3]]
```

Explanation: The first line of `new_path` starts in point `3`, therefore it should be connected to the `prv_path` path ending in `3`. The same goes for the second and third rows. The fourth row of `new_path` begins with the letter `4` therefore it will be connected to the path ending with the letter `4`.

I do not want to connect them using for loops.
Is there an effective method to connect the two above?

Is there a way to do this without using pandas?

Comment: why are you storing paths in a numpy array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly the fastest way to do this if you have 2 `np.ndarray`s, assuming you have integer numbers with values between 1 and the number of rows in the column you wish to merge on in both arrays, using only NumPy:

```
np.hstack((np.sort(prv_path)[new_path[:,0]-1,:-1], new_path))
```

Takes 14.3 µs ± 438 ns on my CPU, **~87.6** times faster than @orlp's solution.

Comment: Thank you. The result should be numpy. I prefer not to use pandas to solve the problem (nor to solve the problem using loops)

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using pandas?

Comment: I don't think this solution would be 87 times faster for larger inputs (I'd reckon the pandas solution has quite a significant baseline overhead), but it's a nice solution regardless.

Answer (score 0):

With `pandas` I know of an efficient solution (using their index for efficiency):

```
prv_df = pd.DataFrame({"i": np.arange(len(prv_path)), "last": prv_path[:,-1]})
prv_df = prv_df.set_index("last")

combo_indices = prv_df.loc[new_path[:,0]]["i"].ravel()
result = np.hstack([prv_path[:,:-1][combo_indices], new_path])
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using pandas?